# Consistency on SVM results

Tags: classification, svm

I have a conversation in my office regarding the results on SVM classification.
As far as I understand it SVM does not contain any random initialization that could produce a different result on different runs.

To make it more concrete if I run the same experiment with the same parameters the results should be the same. This could include if expanded in a cross validation experiment also.

For a 1000 sample binary problem for example if I apply the same cross validation run in a leave-one-out fashion 1000 times (to test every sample) and guarantee that all of the sample and only once it will be used as test set then the order of the cross validation shouldn't matter in the result right? Meaning if I leave the 1st sample as test and then the 2nd, 3rd etc should return the same results if I run with the reverse order 1000th, 999th etc. The same should apply if I train with a different order on the training set (containing though the same number of samples each time).

Can someone assure that this is the case or am I somehow mistaken?